# Translating a datatable in R Shiny

Tags: html, r, datatable, shiny

I've build a R Shiny dashboard with a datatable output. The problem I struggle with is that I want the "datatable captions" to be in German.

For example, I want the search field of the datatable to be labelled as "Suche:"

I've found this code snippet, which works just fine. But I can't find a documentation or help page which gives a full list of the list arguments that can be passed to language.

```
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5, language = list(search = 'Filter:')))
```

I also got the advice to set the "html lang"-tag to "de". I'm not very familar with using HTML within Shiny (dashboard), so I don't know a good way to implement this.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks guys!

Edit: I've added a simplified version of my code:

```
library(semantic.dashboard)

# ui
ui <-dashboardPage(
       dashboardHeader(),
       dashboardSidebar(),
       dashboardBody(
        ### some input,
        ### some plotOutput (output$plot),
        ### some dataTableOutput (output$table) (based on brushed points in the plotOuput)
       )
     )


# server
server <- function(input, output) {

### This works but I can't find any other arguments that can be passed to language:
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5, language = list(search = 'Filter:')))

  data <- ### some data

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ### some plot based on data
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$plot_brush)
    brushedPoints(data, brush = input$plot_brush) %>%
      select(### some variables)
  })


# shinyApp
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Check here https://rstudio.github.io/DT/004-i18n.html

Comment: @A.Suliman: Thanks a lot! That solved it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the context of your script is, but in Shiny's `fluidPage` add something like:

```
<html lang="de"><html>
```

Hope this points you in the right direction, may be better help if you show a simplified version of your script.

P.s. The html lang tag may only work for html elements, which is why we would need to see the script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've added code to my opening post.